# New to debugging. How to go about finding a mistake in this exponential voltage converter

Tags: operational-amplifier

This is the exponential converter I'm trying to set up:

[image]

Marked in purple are the measurements I have taken. As far as I can figure out the first part is working correctly OpAmp is giving the expected output proportional top input voltage. The second part with (-0.74,-0.77,11.39) measurements don't seem to to change with input voltage. I have checked everything 10 times and not sure how to go about debugging this.

I 3x checked every resistor value and replaced every OpAmp and transistor just in case of damage.

Comment: Use a simulator and debug it. Where's the +0.74 volts you talked about? What does the purple "10K" indicate? 10,000 volts?

Comment: 10K is the current value of trimmer pot.  And that 0.74 is a typo, it should be -0.74V@U2.1.

Comment: But where is it?

Comment: Its at Inverting Input of U2.1, I have a -0.77 in the picture, but after remeasuring it was actually -0.74

Comment: I think he means it's at the collector of Q2, which is actually marked -0.77...just like the emitter.  There would be a CE saturation drop IRL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your theory of operation is, but the base of Q2 is grounded.  The common emitter junction won't go below -0.77V, because Q2 will supply plenty of current through its B-E junction.  That means Q1 will remain off as long as the U1.1 output is negative, which it will be unless the inputs sum to less than -5V to overcome the effect of the 5V supply biasing U1.1.  Clearly, as long as Q1 is off, U1.2 will be at roughly VEE, and there won't be any other signal propagating from input to output.

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm following this scheme: https://easyeda.com/SomethingsGoneWrong/Exponential_VCO I found it in a youtube tutorial: https://youtu.be/SE9ZtG0E58g

Comment: It doesn't have any theory of operation on that page, but it looks like it has 3 inputs and none connected to +5.  Like yours, it won't do anything unless the sum of the inputs is negative.

Comment: It is a Voltage controlled oscillator for common eurorack type synth. As far as I understand control voltage can be anywhere from 0 to 15V , I just picked 5V as a example for my debuging.

Comment: I'd say the range is 0 to -15V on the input.   Otherwise, Q1 remains off.  Try it at -5V and see what happens.

Comment: The first OpAmp gave the expected +0.5V but the final output is 0.008V and value doesn't respond to input voltage. Unfortunately it doesn't say what the input should be, but eurorack "standart" CV is usualy 0 to +5v or sometimes -5v to +5v.

Comment: Just to make sure. C2(1u) is a ceramic capacitor with 105 marking, correct?

Comment: That should be 1u.  Remember your emitter coupled stage has an extremely high gain.  Not sure what the linear range is, but if the U1.1 output (Q1 base) isn't pretty close to ground, one of Q1 or Q2 will be off, and the other will be in saturation.  Try maybe a  pot across 1V to -1V, and vary the wiper.  That would probably cover your active range.

Comment: Wow. Seems that this is the case. I adjusted first OpAmp so that gain is 0.01. Now 3V input gives -0.03V and that translates to 1V after adjusting 2nd trimer. Then 3V = 1V, 4V=1.5V, 5V=2.3V etc. Seems that you have solved my problem - thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help!